# C++: virtual void functions error "explicit type is missing (int assumed)"

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, syntax-error, virtual

This program includes a class called collection, which contains virtual void functions. The dynamic array I am making in my main should be able to accept any amount of integers from a file with each line having one number of the file. It allows the user to specify the file name they want to read. Here is the header file:

```
#ifndef Collection_H
#define Collection_H
class collection{
public:
    collection(); //constructor
    virtual void add(int value) = 0; //adds the value to the array
    virtual void remove(int index) = 0; //removes and item from the appropriate index location
    virtual void print() = 0; //prints item of the array comma seperated. 
    virtual int get(int index) = 0; //gets item at a particular index.
    virtual int sum() = 0; //gets the sum of the array
    virtual int size() = 0; //gets the size of the array
};
```

The first question I have for this program is a bit more conceptual: What does virtual actually do and why would you use it and how do you actually implement it? I do know that since you have to make a derived class in order to implement the virtual functions. Therefore, here is my derived class header:

```
// this is the derived collection
#include "Collection.h"
#ifndef derivedcollection_H
#define derivedcollection_H
class derivedcollection: public collection
{
public:
    collection(); //constructor (error is at this line)
    virtual void add(int value) = 0; //adds the value to the array
    virtual void remove(int index) = 0; //removes and item from the appropriate index location
    virtual void print() = 0; //prints item of the array comma seperated. 
    virtual int get(int index) = 0; //gets item at a particular index.
    virtual int sum() = 0; //gets the sum of the array
    virtual int size() = 0; //gets the size of the array
};
#endif
```

My next and final question is more of a simple error I am getting that I don't understand. For the line where collection(); is declared in my derived class derivedcollection, I am getting an error that states "explicit type is missing ('int' assumed)". While this is usually a simple error to fix, it honestly is a bit confusing as to why it gives me this error. How does it gives me this error for my default constructor when I declare it in my derived class header but not my base class header?

Comment: Constructors have the same name as the classes they're within. `derivedcollection`'s constructor must be called `derivedcollection`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtual functions that help in implementing the dynamic polymorphism(a pillar of OOP) are explained in many tutorials in the web.

One of them is [explained here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/122-virtual-functions/)

`virtual void add(int value) = 0;` means it is a ***pure virtual function*** that may not have any definition. The deriving class **must** implement its definition.

Please, note that the `collection` isn't a constructor for the derived class `derivedcollection`.

Thus, the compiler assumes its return type as integer. i.e. its a plain method.

The construct must be `derivedcollection()` instead of `collection()`.

Comment: A pure virtual function can (optionally) have a definition.    However, it must be overridden by a derived class.

Answer (score 1):

There's a ton of literature and YouTube videos out there about `virtual` methods. Regarding the error, your constructor should be `derivedcollection()`, not `collection()`.